# Easy way to manage pretty URLs

Tags: .htaccess, friendly-url

I've been looking forever for a good example to show how to easily create pretty URLs that accomplish the following:

http://www.example.com/posts/some_string_here

to allow a php page to serve up the corresponding record in a database that could be

http://www.example.com/posts.php?id=some_string_here

Using .htaccess and a php page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^posts/(.*)$ ./blognew.php?id=$1
```

And use the following in your PHP file:

```
<?

$showvariable = $_GET['id'];
print "$showvariable";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

that should work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /$1.php?id=$2 [L]

</IfModule>
```

this is kind of regex.

```
^    : matches the beginning of the string.
()   : matches the group (for use as $1,$2 etc.)
.    : matches any character, except for line breaks
*    : matches 0 or more of the preceeding token
/    : matches "/" character, it has to be there
$    : matches the end of the string
```